Trying to loading a csv file into a q table via remote connection and keep getting - '/
I am using the example here to load a csv file...
https://code.kx.com/q/learn/tour/csvs/
But changed it slightly as I need to do this via a remote connection.
I know the file is where it needs to be...where con is the remote connection
q)con "\\cat /temp/example-mount/example.csv"
"id,price,qty"
"kikb,36.05,90"
"hlfe,96.57,84"
"mcej,91.34,63"
"iemn,57.12,93"
"femn,63.64,54"
"engn,94.56,38"
"edhp,63.31,97"
"ggna,72.39,88"
"mjlg,12.04,58"
..

But when I try to load the file...
q)con "t:(\"SFI\";enlist\",\") 0: `:/temp/example-mount/example.csv"
'/
  [0]  con "t:(\"SFI\";enlist\",\") 0: `:/temp/example-mount/example.csv"
       ^

Anyone know what might be wrong with the syntax? I'm guessing it has to do with escaping but I can't get it to work after changing it from the link. I tried via pykx with similar results.

You cannot create a symbol containing special characters such as - without creating as a string with "" and then casting to symbol `$
q)`:/temp/example-mount/example.csv
'/
  [0]  `:/temp/example-mount/example.csv
                            ^
q)`$":/temp/example-mount/example.csv"
`:/temp/example-mount/example.csv

Try
con "t:(\"SFI\";enlist\",\") 0: `$\":/temp/example-mount/example.csv\""

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/datatypes/#symbols

That makes sense. I figured it was the path because I was able to get it to work when I changed the directory to where the file is located but seeing an error of ':

I fixed a typo, the :  was outside the quotes.
